# How do I initialize a final field in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I declared a final field with `private final String s` (Java) or `val s` (Kotlin). During initialization I want to initialize the field with the result of a call to a remote service. In Java I would be able to initialize it in the constructor (e.g. `s = RemoteService.result()`), but in Kotlin I can't figure out how to do that because as far as I can tell the field has to be initialized in the same line it's declared. What's the solution here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set `val` value in init block:

```
class MyClass {

    val s: String

    init {
        s = "value"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also initialize the value with [`by lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) the value will be initialized the first time it is referred. An example

```
val s by lazy { RemoteService.result() }
```

kotlin will guess the type of s from the return type of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#run):

```
class MyClazz {
    val prop = run {
        // do stuff
        // do stuff again
        123 // return expression
    }
}
```

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#run) (emphasis is mine):

> Besides calling `run` on a receiver object, you can use it as a non-extension function. ***Non-extension `run` lets you execute a block of several statements where an expression is required.***

Answer (score 0):

It has been possible to do it simply like this since the very first official stable release of Kotlin:

```
class MyClass {
    val s = RemoteService.result()
}
```